# Installation of TurboVNC using Debian command line/Keyboard issue with LTQ Terminal Beagle Bone

Tags: debian, vnc, beagleboneblack

It would be fantastic if someone could help.

To give some history as to why; I had a problem with my keyboard mapping using TightVNC and so attempted to install tigerVNC and turboVNC on my BeagleBoneBlack (BBB). Below is the link to the keyboard issue I had and also the version of Linux that is currently on my BBB.

[Link to Keyboard mapping issue in this forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346107/keyboard-mapping-wrong-only-in-specific-applications-under-tightvnc)

```
Linux beaglebone 4.14.71-ti-r80 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 5 23:50:11 UTC 2018 armv7                                l GNU/Linux
```

I am only just entering the world of Linux (considering running a separate partition with Ubuntu for this type of development) so I am a problem missing some key foundations as to how to install these packages from the command line.

I have tried things like the below and iterations of, and always get the same message `Unable to locate package tigervnc-common`
:

```
sudo apt-get install turbovnc
sudo apt-get install tigervnc
```

I also looked at the below link from TurboVNC at the digital signatures however this left me a confused with the PGP links and the even `sudo apt-get install debsig-verify` gave me the former error message:

[TurboVNC Digital Signatures](https://turbovnc.org/Downloads/DigitalSignatures)

Can anyone set me straight?

Many thanks in advance for even considering a reply!

P.s. I am accessing the terminal window via an SSH (PUTTY) and the BBB is connected directly to the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the solution that worked for me was found from the below this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/YCiECD0fiII)

```
sudo apt remove qterminal
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install lxterminal
```

When I then restarted my BeagleBone Black I did not have the same keyboard issue with lxterminal.

The end of rather a long but informative saga.

Comment: Juts to add to this in case anyone else has the same problem I continued using tightVNC on the BeagleBone and used tiger VNC on my PC but I think ant tight vnc derivative would do.